# Reversing the output of numbers in Java

Tags: java, reverse, repeat

I'm trying to do a number system calculator but only using the control or repetitive structures. Here's my sample:

```js
int base = 0, given = 0, remainder = 0;
// input given here
System.out.print("The answer is: ");
if (base == 2){
    while(given != 0){
    remainder = given % base;
    given /= base;
    System.out.print("" + remainder);
    }
}
```

And the output goes like this:

```js
Input: 32
The answer is: 000001
```

The question is, how would I reverse the output to 100000 since the binary of 32 is 100000 and not 000001? The condition is not to use anything except the three repetitive structures: for, while and do-while and using decisive structures: if, else-if and for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can concatenate the digits into a `String` and print it after the loop:

```
String output = "";
if (base == 2){
    while(given != 0){
        remainder = given % base;
        given /= base;
        output = remainder + output;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```