# Java Decimal to Hexadecimal using the basics

Tags: java, numbers, hex, decimal, system

I've been working on the number system calculator [(refer to my binary question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387309/reversing-the-output-of-numbers-in-java)
and now i'm stuck at the Hexadecimal part. I've been using switch structure but the output goes like this:

```js
Enter Number: 165
Enter Base: 16
The answer: A105
```

*actual answer should be A5 tho, the remainder 10 which is A is showing up.*

and here's my code:

```js
int given = 0, base = 0, remainder = 0; 
String output = "";
if (base == 2||base == 8){
    while(given != 0){
        remainder = given % base;
        given /= base;
        output = remainder + output;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
else if (base == 16){
    while (given > 0){
        remainder = given % base;
        if (remainder <= 10){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        switch(remainder){
            case 10:System.out.print("A");break;
            case 11:System.out.print("B");break;
            case 12:System.out.print("C");break;
            case 13:System.out.print("D");break;
            case 14:System.out.print("E");break;
            case 15:System.out.print("F");break;
        }
        given /= base;
        output = remainder + output;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Should I choose to continue the switch structure or is there something wrong with my code?

Edit: To make it clear, `output` variable will reverse the value of the specific given. If I have a 37 as a decimal converted to binary, it would output *101001* which the actual answer is *100101*.

Comment: Why not just `String output = Integer.toString(given, base)`?

Comment: @Andreas we should use the basics and we are not allowed to use methods or arrays :(

Comment: Yes, there's something wrong with your code. Several things, but it's so confused it's not clear why you expect it to work. Among other things, you print the hex digits A-F as you go around the loop, but any digit less than that is **added* to output (why?) and then printed only at the end of the loop. Bizarre.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
- Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your example code it is not clear what type the variable `output ` is

Comment: As usual in these questions, there is no decimal here, only binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing A to F letters, and in addition adding the remainder to the output. You should add the letter to the output instead of printing them:

```
while (given > 0){
    remainder = given % base;
    if (remainder >= 10){
      switch(remainder){
        case 10:output = "A" + output;break;
        case 11:output = "B" + output;break;
        case 12:output = "C" + output;break;
        case 13:output = "D" + output;break;
        case 14:output = "E" + output;break;
        case 15:output = "F" + output;break;
      }
    } else {
      output = remainder + output;
    }
    given /= base;
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: oh god Eran you saved the day again thank you so much!! ~^_^~